# How can I compare this big product without using bigint

Tags: c++, biginteger

```
long long a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h;
bool is_greater = a*b*c*d > e*f*g*h;
```

I tried to typecast to `long double` and then use division (ie one variable on lhs by another variable on rhs) but I am getting incorrect output due to precision error.
Mind you I am not even allowed to use `__int128`

Another idea I have is to try out the upper digits first then the lower digits, something like this

```
int M=1e9;
p1 = a/M;
q1 = b/M;
r1 = c/M;
s1 = d/M;

u1 = e/M;
t1 = f/M;
v1 = g/M;
w1 = h/M;

if (p1*q1*r1*s1 > u1*t1*v1*w1) return true;
if (p1*q1*r1*s1 < u1*t1*v1*w1) return false;
//if equal try lower digits:
p2 = a%M;
q2 = b%M;
r2 = c%M;
s2 = d%M;

u2 = e%M;
t2 = f%M;
v2 = g%M;
w2 = h%M;
return (p2*q2*r2*s1 > u2*t2*v2*w1);
```

As @n-m called it this is nothing but bigint , but the reason I am trying to reverse enginner it is because I have another piece of  information. The resultant solution is 256 bits but I have the information that 99.99% of the times the difference will be in the last 128 bit most likely in last 64 bit. I want to use this information to make my code faster(on amortised basis) and yet not suffer from the precision error. So I am juggling bit of tradeoffs on either side.

Comment: This is more of a math/numerical problem, like any problem break it down into smaller ones. e.g. `b*c*d` > `(e*f*g*h)/a` might avoid an overflow.

Comment: @PepijnKramer but `b*c*d` or `e*f*g*h` might overflow

Comment: @PepijnKramer I have already tried out division. Please read the full question details carefully. Additionally all are `long long` so one division wont suffice.

Comment: You might prime factor the things, then eliminate prime factors on both sides. Probably a BigInt isn't that bad ...

Comment: "Mind you I am not even allowed to use __int128" who tells you this? That's not a product owner or manager choice. You have to solve a task and you as the developer pick the technology that suits best. If it's your professor, then there's a reason: because he taught you some math or other approach which is able to solve this and you shall practice exactly that.

Comment: Cast to floats/doubles and take logarithms, that's what they are for

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark but float and double have smaller precision so obviously it won't work for all cases

Comment: @ThomasWeller What is larger, 18367×38111831 or 41149×17011349? (all four are primes)

Comment: "try out the upper digits first then the lower digits" That's basically poor man's bigint. Why not just use a proper bigint library?

Comment: why are you not allowed to use the proper tools? what are you allowed to use instead?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Log seems to be a good idea, I will try it and let you know if it suffers from same precision error as my `long doube` cast.

Comment: i mean suppose you write your own bigint code, would you also not be allowed to use that? You should make more clear what the requirements are

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number in short I am to make it as performance efficient as possible. Writing own bigint don't seem to be very performance efficient.

Comment: @n.m. that's true. But one additional information I have is in 99.9% of the cases the numbers will be very close ie to say comparison with upper digits would be same. Let me know if this information helps you suggest something thats fast on amortised basis.

Comment: I don't know how to use this info, just wanted to say that your idea with poor man's bigint needs further work. Imagine you only need to compare x=(10a+b)(10c+d) and y=(10e+f)(10g+h) where a .. g are single digits, and you are restricted to do multiplications up to 9×9. The full products are (100ac + 10(ad+bc) + bd) and (100eg + 10(eh+fg) + fh). Now, *if* ac == eg, it is not enough to compare only bd and fh, because ad+bc may differ from eh+fg and their contribution to the overall sum is larger. Only if ac == eg *and* ad+bc == eh+fg, you can look at bd and fh. Note ad+bc *may* overflow.

Comment: Now if ac != eg, it is not enough to derive the overall inequality either. You need to do proper summation with carry of all digits. (Take 900000000001 = 634939×1417459 < 900000000023 = 102433×8786231, if you break it up in 4-digits groups, 63×141 > 10×878).

Comment: If approximations won't suffice (eg if logs don't have sufficient precision) then any solution will, in essence, have to implement parts of a big int library

Comment: You will have to do some numerical analysis to confirm, but taking logs as @HighPerformanceMark suggests should be fast and should be able to quickly determine *almost all* of the inequalities. The few close calls remaining can be solved with true bigints.

Answer (score 0):

If

```
a * b * c * > e * f * g * h [1]
```

than

```
a/e * b/f * c/g * d/h > 1 [2]
```

assuming all are positive. In case some of *e, f, g,* or *h* are negative:

- in case odd number of them is negative flip > to <,
- if even number of them is negative, don't change the sign

The conclusion would be: if [2] is true than [1] is also true (again, pay attention to the sign)

Pseudo code:

```
int p = 0;
for (x in [efgh])
    if (x < 0)
        p += 1;

if (pow(-1, p) < 0)
    flip_the_sign;
```

Comment: You cannot compute `a/e` etc. exactly. Floating point division is no better than floating point multiplication, which is known not to work.

Comment: Good point, I missed that. Of course OP could define epsilon which would be tolerable error. For instance 1 - (a/e *....d/h) > epsilon.